# Band analysis in catia

Tags: vba, catia

I need code for measuring distance between 2 products im catia using VBA. I dont want to use groups to measure. I want to use distance.firstproduct and distance.secondproduct in the code instead of using distance.firstgroup. Can some one help me with the code.
Thank you

```
sub main()
Dim MyDoc As Document
Set MyDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim MyProduct As Product
Set MyProduct = MyDoc.Product

Dim Product1 As Product
Dim Product2 As Product

Set Product1 = MyProduct.Products.Item("Part1.1")
Set Product2 = MyProduct.Products.Item("Part2.1")


Dim MySelection As Selection
Set MySelection = MyDoc.Selection

MySelection.Clear

Dim cDistances As Distances
Set cDistances = MyProduct.GetTechnologicalObject("Distances")

Dim MyDistance As Distance
set mydistance=cdistance.add


MyDistance.ComputationType = catDistanceComputationTypebetweentwo
MyDistance.MeasureType = catDistanceMeasureTypeMinimum
Set MyDistance.Firstproduct=product1  '<----Error Line
set myDistance.secondproduct=product2  '<----Error Line

MeasureDistance = MyDistance.Value

MySelection.Clear
end sub
```

Comment: Could you share some code you have written so far?

Comment: hi,i have added the code to the question which i have written so far please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirstProduct` and `SecondProduct` properties are Read Only, as stated on the Catia CAA Documentation:

> Property FirstProduct( ) As Product (Read Only)
>
> Returns the product belonging to the first group that realizes the
>   minimum distance.

You must create the groups and add the product to the group to evaluate the distance.